# Error regarding ttm-prepare.ps1 of DXA 1.6

Tags: web8, dxa

I'm installing DXA 1.6 in SDL Web 8.
Regarding the documentation of DXA, I should run the `ttm-prepare.ps1`.
Error occurred. 
Error message:

> Add-TtmCdEnvironment: CdEnvironmentData's property 'DiscoveryEndpointUrl' should be unique.The reason of competition: 'Demo1CD'.

`Demo1CD` is a CDEnvironment used now.

Do I need create a new CD Environment or something else that are not mentioned in documentation? 
If a new CD Environment whose purpose is "Staging" is needed, do I also need to install all the delivery services (content service, deployer service) and create new databases? I created the picture below, is my thinking right?(The environment to create is used for DXA)
Could I only create environment for staging purpose, excluding environment for live purpose. Will this make import of DXA fail?
[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The screenshot is a bit hard to read, since I don't know Japanese. Can you edit your question and add some detail on what was entered for each parameter?

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't mention that. I have modified my question. Thanks for your remind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ttm-prepare.ps1` script ensures that you have CD Environments with purpose `Staging` and (optionally) `Live` defined in Topology Manager.

If you already have such CD Environments defined, it will use those. If not, it will define them for you, but you can't use a Discovery Service which is already used for another CD Environment (with another purpose).

For clarity: DXA ships with predefined Business Process Types which assume you have the typical Staging & Live CD Topology. The `ttm-prepare.ps1` is used to ensure the Topology Manager side of things is setup before importing into CMS (otherwise importing the predefined BPTs would fail).

Comment: I have a CD Environment but its purpose's name is not 'Staging'. Do I need to create a new Environment before run the script? If so, I also need to create a new Discovery Service?

Comment: You don't have to define the CD Environment in Topology Manager; the `ttm-prepare.ps1` script will do that for you, but you do have to ensure you have an actual CD Environment (incl. Discovery Service) which you can register and is not in use for something else yet.

Comment: On your question about Staging and Live: it is possible to only register a Staging environment.